# Enable a corresponding field when checkbox is checked

Tags: jquery, html

My requirement is to enable a `<select>` element when it's corresponding checkbox is checked.

I need have many rows of this and writing separate code and ids for each element is time and resource intensive. I need to keep the performance as much as possible.

Following cde works but it's repetitive. I'm sure there's some selector to do all the work in one statement. But i don't know about that.

Currently i have tried this:

```
document.getElementById('austria').onchange = function() {
    document.getElementById('austria-n').disabled = !this.checked;
};
document.getElementById('belgium').onchange = function() {
    document.getElementById('belgium-n').disabled = !this.checked;
};
```

Codepen: http://codepen.io/VeeK727/pen/zGBvVv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is just simple you can find easily:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() { 

         $(this).parent().next().attr("disabled", !this.checked);

 });
```

Check your updated code [Here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xGOZxE)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks. What's with the down votes?

Comment: You have to put your sample code with question as your tried.